# Can you use a rental car/car share to pass the road test for a Canadian driving license?

Tags: canada, driving-license

The [page on converting your foreign license](http://www.icbc.com/driver-licensing/moving-bc/Pages/Moving-from-another-country.aspx) to a Canadian one says:

> Step 2: With two years' of non-learner driving experience, you'll need to take the Class 5 road test.

Is it possible for me to use a rental car/car share such as Zipcar to pass the test? Or do they want to see the owner of the car before taking you for a spin?

Answer (score 2):

This [page](http://www.icbc.com/driver-licensing/visit-dl-office/Pages/Prepare-road-test-appointment.aspx) says that you need to bring the car's insurance and registration. That might be difficult with a borrowed/rented car.

Comment: Rental cars do provide you with the insurance and registration, otherwise what would you show at a police stop?

Comment: The one time I was stopped in a rental I gave them my license and told them it was a rental--they didn't ask for the other documents.

Answer (score 1):

The ICBC mentions that:

> If you plan to use a vehicle from a car sharing co-op or company, please check in with them for more details.

So they don't really care who the car belongs to. However the much bigger problem is that [you need a second driver](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/why-do-i-need-to-bring-a-second-driver-with-me-in-case-i-dont-pass-the-canadian) to get to the test in the first place, so self-driving yourself to ICBC is impossible. The best alternative I've found so far (assuming I can't get someone to waste 3 hours of their time to drive with me to the test) is to pay a driving school to loan you a car for the driving exam.