# Why do I need to bring a second driver with me in case I don't pass the British Columbia, Canadian road test?

Tags: canada, driving-license

The [page on converting your foreign license](http://www.icbc.com/driver-licensing/moving-bc/Pages/Moving-from-another-country.aspx) to a British Columbia one says:

> Step 2: With two years' of non-learner driving experience, you'll need to take the Class 5 road test. Note: **Bring another qualified driver with you for your test in case you don’t pass.**

Why would that be necessary? I assume that even if I fail the test my license is still valid within Canada (up to 90 days) and therefore I can just drive away if I fail the examination.

Comment: I think they'll confiscate your license. If you have a new driver permit, you would keep that so you can practice more.

Comment: Just for the record, this is about converting to a *British Columbia* license.  Canada, per se, does not have driver's licenses.  The rules for licensing are unique to every province and territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fail the road test your original license will be taken away and therefore you won't be able to legally drive the car back to wherever you live. Of course, you could probably park the car near the examination office and return for it later, but the recommended approach is to have the second driver waiting beforehand.

If you don't own a car in BC you'd probably rent one from a driving school anyway, so your driving instructor will be your second driver.

Comment: The logic is that before the test, all they had to go on was that fact that you had passed your foreign driving test so they assumed you were safe to drive.  After the test they know you are not safe to drive (so forbid it).

Comment: @MartinBonner in theory yes. But then again ICBC converts American licenses without an exam, even though they're literally the easiest licenses in the whole world to get. So much for safety.